# retrieve data from the table where only those defects are included on which the progress is not updated for more than 1 hour

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKM19.png)

AUDIT TABLE

```
TIME  DEFECT ACTION FIELD  
01:01 123    UPDATE PROGRESS  
00:03 123    UPDATE PROGRESS  
01:00 566    UPDATE PROGRESS  
00:05 123    UPDATE PROGRESS  
10:01 128    UPDATE PROGRESS
```

DEFECT TABLE

```
DEFECT PROGRESS   
123    PQR  
128    XYZ  
566    ABC
```

I would like to retrieve the data from the defect table where only those defects are included on which the progress is not updated for more than 1 hour

expected output

DEFECT TABLE

```
DEFECT       PROGRESS  
566           ABC  
128           XYZ
```

Comment: What data type is the `time` column?

Comment: it is actually a timestamp field having DATE as the data type.

Comment: `date` and `timestamp` are two different things

Comment: Why isn't 123 in the expected output? between 01:01 and 00:03 (which is supposedly the next day) is more than one hour as well?